# SQL Server Pivot multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a following table

```
c1  b1  y1  sk  sales   cogs
in  b2b 2012    s1  1000    900
in  b2b 2012    s2  1100    1050
in  b2b 2011    s1  1000    900
```

I want to pivoting on multiple columns. I tried several but not able to generate below output

```
c1  b1  sk  sales_2012  sales_2011  cogs_2012   cogs_2011
in  b2b s1  1000         1000            900    900
in  b2b s2  1100                     1050
```

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide what code you've used to try to make this work.

Comment: I build    `SELECT  *
FROM         [dbo].s1 PIVOT (sum(net_sales) FOR y1 IN ([2013],[2012])) pvttable


SELECT  *
FROM         [dbo].s1 cross apply (
select net_sales, sum(net_sales) union all
select cogs, sum(cogs)) c(col,val) pvttable`. I know I am far away what I am expecting..

Comment: Can I make a recommendation?  Take the name of your question, paste it into the search bar up at the top right, and see what comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it pretty easily with a union in a single pivot.

```
Select *
FROM
(SELECT c1,  b1, 'sales_' + CAST(y1 AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Dimension,  sk,  sales AS Value
  FROM dbo.s1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c1,  b1, 'cogs_' + CAST(y1 AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Dimension,  sk,  cogs AS Value
  FROM dbo.s1
   ) AS p
  PIVOT
  (
  SUM(Value)
  FOR Dimension IN
  ( sales_2012, sales_2011  , cogs_2012   , cogs_2011)
  ) AS pvt
```

Comment: If `y1` is a numeric type, you'll need to cast it to varchar for the concatenations.

Comment: Thanks wdosanjos I missed that. I've edited the post to add the cast.